# trouble understanding implementation of hash table with chaining

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable, chaining

I'm studying on hash table with chaining in java by its implementation. The trouble is about `get()` method. An index value is determined with `key.hashCode() % table.length`. Assume that the table size is `10` and key.hashCode() is `124` so index is found as `4`. In for each loop `table[index]` is started from `table[4]`, AFAIK index is being incremented one by one `4,5,6,7... so on`. But what about indices `0,1,2,3`? Are they been checked? (I think no) Isn't there any possibility that occurring of key on one of the indices? (I think yes). The other issue that there are `null` checks but initially there is no any `null` assignment for `key` and `value`. So how can the checking work? Is `null` assigned as soon as `private LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>[] table` is declared?

```
// Data Structures: Abstraction and Design Using Java, Koffman, Wolfgang

package KW.CH07;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

/**
 * Hash table implementation using chaining.
 * @param <K> The key type
 * @param <V> The value type
 * @author Koffman and Wolfgang
 **/
public class HashtableChain<K, V> 
// Insert solution to programming project 7, chapter -1 here
    implements KWHashMap<K, V> {

    /** The table */
    private LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>[] table;
    /** The number of keys */
    private int numKeys;
    /** The capacity */
    private static final int CAPACITY = 101;
    /** The maximum load factor */
    private static final double LOAD_THRESHOLD = 3.0;

    // Note this is equivalent to java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry
    /** Contains key-value pairs for a hash table. 
        @param <K> the key type
        @param <V> the value type
     */
    public static class Entry<K, V> 
// Insert solution to programming project 6, chapter -1 here
    {

        /** The key */
        private final K key;
        /** The value */
        private V value;

        /**
         * Creates a new key-value pair.
         * @param key The key
         * @param value The value
         */
        public Entry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves the key.
         * @return The key
         */
        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves the value.
         * @return The value
         */
        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value.
         * @param val The new value
         * @return The old value
         */
        @Override
        public V setValue(V val) {
            V oldVal = value;
            value = val;
            return oldVal;
        }

// Insert solution to programming exercise 3, section 4, chapter 7 here
    }

    // Constructor
    public HashtableChain() {
        table = new LinkedList[CAPACITY];
    }

    // Constructor for test purposes
    HashtableChain(int capacity) {
        table = new LinkedList[capacity];
    }

    /**
     * Method get for class HashtableChain.
     * @param key The key being sought
     * @return The value associated with this key if found;
     *         otherwise, null
     */
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        int index = key.hashCode() % table.length;
        if (index < 0) {
            index += table.length;
        }
        if (table[index] == null) {
            return null; // key is not in the table.
        }
        // Search the list at table[index] to find the key.
        for (Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[index]) {
            if (nextItem.getKey().equals(key)) {
                return nextItem.getValue();
            }
        }

        // assert: key is not in the table.
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method put for class HashtableChain.
     * @post This key-value pair is inserted in the
     *       table and numKeys is incremented. If the key is already
     *       in the table, its value is changed to the argument
     *       value and numKeys is not changed.
     * @param key The key of item being inserted
     * @param value The value for this key
     * @return The old value associated with this key if
     *         found; otherwise, null
     */
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        int index = key.hashCode() % table.length;
        if (index < 0) {
            index += table.length;
        }
        if (table[index] == null) {
            // Create a new linked list at table[index].
            table[index] = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        // Search the list at table[index] to find the key.
        for (Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[index]) {
            // If the search is successful, replace the old value.
            if (nextItem.getKey().equals(key)) {
                // Replace value for this key.
                V oldVal = nextItem.getValue();
                nextItem.setValue(value);
                return oldVal;
            }
        }

        // assert: key is not in the table, add new item.
        table[index].addFirst(new Entry<>(key, value));
        numKeys++;
        if (numKeys > (LOAD_THRESHOLD * table.length)) {
            rehash();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /** Returns true if empty 
        @return true if empty
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return numKeys == 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: For a _chained_ hash table, the index is never incremented; there is no possibility of the entry occuring in any other bucket than `table[4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume that the table size is 10 and key.hashCode() is 124 so index is found as 4. In for each loop table[index] is started from table[4]

Correct.

> there are null checks but initially there is no any null assignment for key and value. So how can the checking work?

When an array of objects is initialized, all values are set to `null`.

> index is being incremented one by one 4,5,6,7... so on. But what about indices 0,1,2,3? Are they been checked? (I think no) Isn't there any possibility that occurring of key on one of the indices? (I think yes).

Looks like there's some misunderstanding here. First, think of the data structure like this (with data having already been added to it):

```
table:
[0] -> null
[1] -> LinkedList -> item 1 -> item 2 -> item 3
[2] -> LinkedList -> item 1
[3] -> null
[4] -> LinkedList -> item 1 -> item 2
[5] -> LinkedList -> item 1 -> item 2 -> item 3 -> item 4
[6] -> null
```

Another important point is that the hash code for a given `key` should not change, so it will always map to the same index in the table.

So say we call `get` with a value who's hash code maps it to 3, then we know that it's not in the table:

```
if (table[index] == null) {
    return null; // key is not in the table.
}
```

If another key comes in that maps to 1, now we need to iterate over the LinkedList:

```
 // LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> list = table[index]
 for (Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[index]) {
     // iterate over item 1, item 2, item 3 until we find one that is equal.
     if (nextItem.getKey().equals(key)) {
         return nextItem.getValue();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you aren't quite visualizing your hash table correctly. There are two equally good simple implementations of a hash table.

Method 1 uses linked lists: An array (well, Vector, actually) of linked lists.

Given a "key", you derive a hash value for that key(*). You take the remainder of that hash value relative to the current size of the vector, let's call that "x". Then you sequentially search the linked list that vector[x] points to for a match to your key.

(*) You hope that the hash values will be reasonably well-distributed. There are complex algorithms for doing this. Let's hope your JVM implementation of HashCode does a good job of this.

Method 2 avoids linked lists: you create a Vector and compute an index into the Vector (as above). Then you look at the Vector.get(x). If that's the key you want, your return the corresponding value. Let's assume it's not. Then you look at Vector.get(x+1), Vector.get(x+2), etc. Eventually, one of the following three things will happen:

a) You find the key you are looking for. Then you return the corresponding value.
b) you find an empty entry (key == null). Return null or whatever value you have chosen to mean "this isn't the droid you're looking for".
c) you have examined every entry in the Vector. Again, return null or whatever.

Checking for (c) is a precaution, so that if the Hash Table happens to be full you won't loop forever. If the hash table is about to be full (you can keep a count of how many entries have been used) you should reallocate a bigger hash table.  IDeally, you want to keep the hash table sparse enough that you never get anywhere *near* searching the whole table: that vitiates the whole purpose of a hash table -- that you can search it in much less than linear time, ideally in order 1 (that is, the number of comparisons is <= a small constant). I would suggest that you allocate a Vector that is at least 10x the number of entries you expect to put in it.

The use of the word "chaining" in you questions suggests to me that you want to implement the second type of hash table.

Btw, you should never use 10 as the size of a hash table. The size should be a prime number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A key point that makes a hash table work is that it needs to agree with the equals method: say you override the equals method on your class, you must override hashcode and implement it such that if two instances return true for equals, they should return the same hashcode value. The reverse is not necessarily true: two instances with the same hashcode value might not be equal. This plays into how the hash map works: first sort by hashcode, then on collisions, use the equals method.